# Incrementing while inserting sql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a table as below:

```
Department     Date          Budget
-----------------------------------
D1             2010-01-01      100
D2             2010-01-01      200
...             ...            ...
```

Is there a way to write an insert statement that autoincrements the month and budget for a particular department?

For instance, I want to insert data for 2010 from Jan to Dec for department D1 with increments of 10 each month. So the resultant table should look something like below

```
Department     Date          Budget
------------------------------------
D1             2010-01-01      100
D2             2010-01-01      200
D1             2010-02-01      110
D1             2010-03-01      120
D1             2010-04-01      130
...            ...             ...
```

I know this can be achieved through some scripting, but is there a way to achieve this through just insert and select statements ?

Using SQL Server (or) Postgres

Comment: in postgres you could `insert ..select..generate_series` but you should show your current insert to make clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Postgres:

```
insert into the_table (department, "date", budget)
select d.department, 
       d.date + interval '1 month' * row_number() over (order by g.i),
       d.budget + row_number() over (order by g.i)  * 10
from the_table d, generate_series(1,11) as g(i)
where d.department = 'D1';
```

This assumes that at the time when this is run, only a single row exists for department `D1`

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
insert into Table values
('D1',Dateadd(month,1,
(select top 1 Date from Table order by Date Desc)),budget)
```

Answer (score 0):

using recursive cte

```
;With cte(Department,[Date], Budget)
AS
(
SELECT 'D1','2010-01-01', 100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D2','2010-01-01', 200
)
,cte2 AS 
( 
       SELECT 0 AS val , 
              0 AS val2 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT val +1, 
              val2+10 
       FROM   cte2 
       WHERE  val<11 )
INSERT INTO the_table (department, [date], budget)    
SELECT department, 
           [date], 
           CASE 
                  WHEN rnk=0 THEN budget 
                  ELSE budget+val2 
           END AS Budget 
    FROM   ( 
                    SELECT   department, 
                             val2, 
                             Dateadd(month,val,[date])AS [Date], 
                             budget, 
                             Row_number()OVER(PArtition by Department ORDER BY [Date])-1 AS Rnk 
                    FROM     Cte2 , 
                             Cte )dt 
    WHERE  dt.department='D1'
```

Result

```
department    Date                  Budget
-------------------------------------------
D1          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     100
D1          2010-02-01 00:00:00.000     110
D1          2010-03-01 00:00:00.000     120
D1          2010-04-01 00:00:00.000     130
D1          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000     140
D1          2010-06-01 00:00:00.000     150
D1          2010-07-01 00:00:00.000     160
D1          2010-08-01 00:00:00.000     170
D1          2010-09-01 00:00:00.000     180
D1          2010-10-01 00:00:00.000     190
D1          2010-11-01 00:00:00.000     200
D1          2010-12-01 00:00:00.000     210
```